# Using the Apple Wireless Keyboard with an iPad with PC/Mac-like keyboard commands

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ios, jailbreak, command-line

I have jailbroken iPad 2 (iOS5.1.1) and an Apple wireless Bluetooth keyboard that I use for typing on the iPad. Although the keyboard is a joy to use, I can't use it for much else other than typing documents and creating notes.

I'd like to be able to use some kind of keyboard shortcuts to move around/switch between apps, use shortcuts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> in the browser and so on.

Is this somehow possible? And if so how?

Comment: I can't comment on Jailbreak-based solutions, but iOS itself only responds to a small subset of computer-based commands. It should work well with things like <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to make an item bold-faced for instance, or <kbd>opt</kbd> + e to add an accent mark above a letter. Generally any commands you can use in Pages on a Mac to modify your text you can use on an iPad. You may get more fully-featured answers though from someone with a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 3):

[BeeKeyboard](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/14/beekeyboard/) is a tweak available via Cydia that adds the ability to create custom keyboard shortcuts. I'm not sure if it can do app-switching shortcuts, but you can install a plugin called BeeSafari to add some browser shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

When you’re in a programme, press and hold the <kbd>CMD</kbd> button, a pop-up should appear giving you a list of commands.